# Change position of an exact number of elements in an array

Tags: c, arrays

Let's say we have an **array of m elements** and we want to change **randomly** the position of **exactly n** of them, where of course 2 <= n <= m.

For example: if we have this array of **10** ints {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10} and we ask for **4** of its elements to change positions randomly, a result could be {3 2 1 4 5 6 10 8 9 7}

What is the simplest way to program this in ANSI C? (pseudocode will also be just fine)

Comment: "Simplest way" -- can you show your own not-so-simple implementation?

Comment: For 2 elements a1 and a2 to swap positions it could be easy: tmp=a1, a1=a2, a2=tmp. For 3 elements a1, a2 and a3 it could be: tmp1=a1, tmp2=a2, a1=a3, a2=tmp1 and a3=tmp, but that's not random. I would like to generalize this to any number of random changes(swaps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1). Generate a list of n random unique numbers between 1 and m.  This list should NOT be sorted.    Eg, for your example, the list could have been [10,7,1,3]

Step 2) do something like :

```
int save = array[list[0]];
For (i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
  Array[list[i]] = array[list[i+1]];
}
Array[list[n-1]] = save;
```

Edit: actually, you'll have to have subtract 1 from each list[whatever] to allow for zero-based arrays - but I'm sure you get the idea :)

Comment: That's very close to what I was thinking of as well and helps me a lot. I actually made a function that chooses randomly some elements of the array, but I didn't know how to continue.

Comment: This only picks cycles, and the example in the question can't be generated from this algorithm. Not that the answer is wrong since it answers the question as written since the question doesn't say what "random" means.

Comment: By "random" I mean that the elements which will change positions must be selected randomly among the others.

Comment: @Vassilis check my answer. i am curious what others think of it

Answer (score 0):

since at least two numbers must be swapped, i would pick two random numbers from array first and then swap them. they are added to array that holds swapped indexes. if there's more to swap, pick another number different than swapped ones and swap it with one of the previously swapped numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void print_arr(int a[], int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
        printf("\n");
}

void swap(int a[], int i, int j) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}

int next_idx(int swapped[], int s_count, int size) {
    int n, i;
    char in_arr;
    while (1) {
        in_arr = 0;
        n = rand() % size;
        for (i = 0; i < s_count; i++) {
            if (swapped[i] == n) {
                in_arr = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!in_arr) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

void swap2_or_more(int a[], int size,int count) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, j, s_count = 0;
    int swapped[size];
    i = rand() % size;
    swapped[s_count] = i;
    s_count++;
    do {
        j = rand() % size;
    } while (i == j);  // make sure indexes are different
    swapped[s_count] = j;
    s_count++;

    swap(a, i, j);
    count -= 2;
    while (count) {
        i = next_idx(swapped, s_count, size);
        j = rand() % s_count;
        swap(a, i, swapped[j]);
        swapped[s_count] = i;
        s_count++;
        count--;
    }
    printf("swapped indexes:\n");
    print_arr(swapped, s_count);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    swap2_or_more(a, 10, 5);
    printf("array after swap:\n");
    print_arr(a, 10);
    return 0;
}
```